# Passing data between view controllers using protocol and delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, nsstring, protocols

I am trying to push a string text to viewcontroller 1 from my viewcontroller 2 using protocols and delegate. I am new to this method of passing data so forgive me if I seem ignorant in any way. The string color always return null. I will post the code I have so far and if it helps, im using navigation controller and using the navigation back button to go from ViewController 2 to ViewController 1.

Viewcontroller 2

.h

```
@protocol PassString <NSObject>
@required
 - (void) setSecondFavoriteColor:(NSString *)string;
 @end
 @interface ViewController2 : UIViewController{
 UIButton *button; 
 NSString *ee
  id <PassString> delegate;
  }
  @property (retain) id delegate;
```

ViewController 2

.m

```
@synthesize delegate;   

-(void)button{
ee = @"Blue Color";
[[self delegate] setSecondFavoriteColor:ee];
```

ViewController 1.h

```
@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController <PassString>{
NSString*color;
 }
 @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *color
```

ViewController 1.m

```
- (void)setSecondFavoriteColor:(NSString *)string
{
color = string;
NSLog(@"%@",color);
}
```

Comment: I did, if I didn't I wouldn't even make it this far being new at this. And I have to pass it between view controllers a certain way using protcol and delegates.

Comment: May be You forgot to set ViewController2.delegate = Viewcontroller1

Comment: Why do you have to do it "a certain way"?  Is this for a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple things I noticed in your code, your property should contain the specified protocol:

```
@property (retain) id <PassString> delegate;
```

And at some point in the class that's implementing the delegate methods, you have to assign the delegate to view controller 1. For example:

```
[viewController2Instance setPassingDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I forgot to set delegate. Thanks